# Intergration asp Web Form with asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

How to intergrate asp web form use visual basic with asp MVC 4 use C#.Help me!!!
I have issue:

[image]

File Global.asax.cs:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

File Login.aspx.vb:

```
Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private WithEvents objA2Global As A2Component.A2Global ' RapidISGlobal  ' A2Component.A2Global
```

File Global.asax:

```
%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="RapidIS.MvcApplication" Language="VB" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

File Route config:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a copy of your error, and your code, in your question. Images are useless (even though they can now be seen).

Comment: I add some please help me!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a partial class which is divided into two files, you must write the same class declaration in both file. I  have read the error and it says that you have to use the same enhiritance to those files.